# Can I assign a template engine to static routes

Tags: spark-java

Is there a (simple) way to assign a template engine to staticFiles ?

For example: `staticFiles.defaultEngine( new JadeTemplateEngine() )`

TIA

Comment: Why would you use Jade in your static files? You can use Jade to every access route you declare

Comment: I can do it for specific routes defined with get/post/etc. but not for static pages. I use staticFiles for real web pages used to control/monitor the REST endpoints; I wanted to use jade to define those pages. It's not a big deal - I can create raw html if necessary.